# Reading bits from USB input

Tags: c#, usb

I want to build a circuit that will send some bits to the computer. I was thinking about using the usb port using the data+ and data- cable to send the bits to the computer, however I
m having some problems figuring out how to capture these bits.
How can I capture these bits in C#, without having to write any drivers?

I have read many of previous posts on reading from USB, but none of those answered my question.

Comment: http://libusbdotnet.sourceforge.net/V2/Index.html

Comment: I'm guessing you've read this very descriptive tutorial? http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84338/making-usb-c-friendly/

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution you need a device that will translate your I/O signals to signals your USB port understands.

I have used the [U421 in the past](http://www.kadtronix.com/usbhidapi.htm#U4x1Device), they have a library that you just load the DLL using P/Invoke then you can send signals to the pins on the chip. You will then need to wire whatever you want to read to the chip (*correctly*, but that is beyond the scope of Stack Overflow, you may want to try [Electronics.StackExchange.com](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)). See the  `U4x1 Application Notes` section on [the USBMicro website](http://www.usbmicro.com/) for example code and wiring diagrams.

Example code from the webiste:

```
⁄⁄ needed to import the .dll
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    public class USBm
        {
        public static byte BitA0 = 0x00;
        public static byte BitA1 = 0x01;
        public static byte BitA2 = 0x02;
        public static byte BitA3 = 0x03;
        public static byte BitA4 = 0x04;
        public static byte BitA5 = 0x05;
        public static byte BitA6 = 0x06;
        public static byte BitA7 = 0x07;
        public static byte BitB0 = 0x08;
        public static byte BitB1 = 0x09;
        public static byte BitB2 = 0x0A;
        public static byte BitB3 = 0x0B;
        public static byte BitB4 = 0x0C;
        public static byte BitB5 = 0x0D;
        public static byte BitB6 = 0x0E;
        public static byte BitB7 = 0x0F;

⁄⁄  USBm.dll - C# pInvoke examples
⁄⁄  "Commands"
⁄⁄      [DllImport("USBm.dll", EntryPoint = "USBm_FindDevices", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        [DllImport("USBm.dll")]
        public static extern bool USBm_FindDevices();
        [DllImport("USBm.dll")]
        public static extern int USBm_NumberOfDevices();
        [DllImport("USBm.dll")]
        public static extern bool USBm_DeviceValid(int Device);
        [DllImport("USBm.dll")]
        public static extern bool USBm_About(StringBuilder About);
        [DllImport("USBm.dll")]
        public static extern bool USBm_Version(StringBuilder Version);
        [DllImport("USBm.dll")]
        public static extern bool USBm_Copyright(StringBuilder Copyright);
        [DllImport("USBm.dll")]
        public static extern bool USBm_DeviceMfr(int Device, StringBuilder Mfr);
        [DllImport("USBm.dll")]
        public static extern bool USBm_DeviceProd(int Device, StringBuilder Prod);
        [DllImport("USBm.dll")]
        public static extern int USBm_DeviceFirmwareVer(int Device);
        [DllImport("USBm.dll")]
        public static extern bool USBm_DeviceSer(int Device, StringBuilder dSer);
        [DllImport("USBm.dll")]
        public static extern int USBm_DeviceDID(int Device);
        [DllImport("USBm.dll")]
        public static extern int USBm_DevicePID(int Device);
        [DllImport("USBm.dll")]
        public static extern int USBm_DeviceVID(int Device);
        [DllImport("USBm.dll")]
        public static extern bool USBm_DebugString(StringBuilder DBug);
        [DllImport("USBm.dll")]
        public static extern bool USBm_RecentError(StringBuilder rError);
        [DllImport("USBm.dll")]
        public static extern bool USBm_ClearRecentError();
        [DllImport("USBm.dll")]
        public static extern bool USBm_SetReadTimeout(uint TimeOut);
        [DllImport("USBm.dll")]
        public static extern bool USBm_ReadDevice(int Device, byte[] inBuf);
        [DllImport("USBm.dll")]
        public static extern bool USBm_WriteDevice(int Device, byte[] outBuf);
        [DllImport("USBm.dll")]
        public static extern bool USBm_CloseDevice(int Device);
        }
```

Example of function calling

```
⁄⁄ Test USBm device attached

if ( !USBm.USBm_FindDevices() )
    { 
    MessageBox.Show( string.Format("No Device Present"), "USBm Devices", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information );
    return;
    }  ⁄⁄ implied else

⁄⁄Walk the USBm.dll functions

⁄⁄ some containers
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( 200 );
bool result = false;  ⁄⁄ return values

⁄⁄ .DLL FindDevices  returns the number of devices
result = USBm.USBm_FindDevices();

⁄⁄ return the number of devices
int TotalDevices = USBm.USBm_NumberOfDevices();
int Device = TotalDevices -1;  ⁄⁄ only One device is ever attached so ...

⁄⁄ .DLL About info
result = USBm.USBm_About( sb );

⁄⁄ .DLL Version info
result = USBm.USBm_Version( sb );

⁄⁄ .DLL Copyright info
result = USBm.USBm_Copyright( sb );

⁄⁄ Device Valid
result = USBm.USBm_DeviceValid( Device );

⁄⁄ Device Manufacturer
result = USBm.USBm_DeviceMfr( Device, sb );

⁄⁄ Device Product String
result = USBm.USBm_DeviceProd( Device, sb );

⁄⁄ Device Firmware Version
int FirmVer = USBm.USBm_DeviceFirmwareVer(Device);

⁄⁄ Device SerialNumber [ ]
result = USBm.USBm_DeviceSer(Device, sb);

⁄⁄ Device DiD
int DID = USBm.USBm_DeviceDID(Device);

⁄⁄ Device PiD
int PID = USBm.USBm_DevicePID(Device);

⁄⁄ Device ViD
int VID = USBm.USBm_DeviceVID(Device);

⁄⁄ Device Debug String
result = USBm.USBm_DebugString(sb);

⁄⁄ Device Recent Error - always returns true
result = USBm.USBm_RecentError(sb);

⁄⁄ Device Clear Recent Error
result = USBm.USBm_ClearRecentError();

⁄⁄ Device SetReadTimeout [ sixteen-bit millisecond value]
uint tOUT = 3000;
result = USBm.USBm_SetReadTimeout(tOUT);

⁄⁄ Device WriteDevice [ 8 byte to write (device raw commands)]
byte[] OutBuf = { 0, 21, 3, 65, 8, 17, 60, 0 };
result = USBm.USBm_WriteDevice(Device, OutBuf);

⁄⁄ Device ReadDevice [ ]
byte[] InBuf = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
result = USBm.USBm_ReadDevice(Device, InBuf);

// Device CloseDevice [ ]
result = USBm.USBm_CloseDevice(Device);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use ready-made custom drivers. Here is example of [libusb-win32](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/libusb-win32/wiki). It install upper-filter device driver and allow you to send standard/documented or even custom commands to USB.

P.S. Scroll down until 'Links' section to find a link for C#/VB.NET download and code examples.